# Create div when file is created

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a "live" HTML page that updates based upon dynamic data sources.
The data source could be individual files, or could be entries in a database.

My thought is to create a `<div>` (animated to pop on the screen via jQueryUI) for each data source as it comes online, with its data updating periodically.  Then, when the the timestamped data becomes stale, remove the div.

I have some ideas, but want to hear different implementation strategies suggestions on the best way to handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://socket.io/ for node.js. If you have to use PHP, you might be able to use something like Ratchet http://socketo.me/

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a shared host, so I cannot install websockets.

Comment: Are your only access privileges SFTP? Because if that's the case (and you're not allowed to run shell scripts), then the only options I can think of would be long polling (which http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code has nice examples of) or periodic AJAX requests.

Comment: I have ssh (without root) and ftp access.  My solution was periodic AJAX, but it looks like there might be workarounds to installing python libs without root that might work.